# Three.js object.rotation details

Tags: three.js, rotation, euler-angles

i read three.js docs about rotation so i know that three.js uses intrinsic (Tait-Bryan) ordering on Euler angles when applying rotation.
Then as i remember they get converted to quaternions in the backend to prevent gimbal lock.

My goal is to apply a yzy rotation.

Lets think of an angle `phi`.

Lets think of another angle `theta`.

Theta is constant an arbitirary value that i will use as a step.

In the render loop,

```
function render(){
   object.rotation.y = phi;
   object.rotation.z += theta;
   object.rotation.y = -phi;
}
```

I get confused about what happens here.

Are these the steps of a YZY Euler angle application? 
How rotation works in three.js internally?
Thank you for help.

To be more clear, 
is

```
   object.rotation.x = val1;
   object.rotation.y = val2;
   object.rotation.z = val3;
```

the same as

```
   object.rotation.setRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(val1,val2,val3,'XYZ'));
```

also the same as

```
   let vec = new THREE.Vector3(object's current normalized direction vector);
   vec.applyEuler(new THREE.Euler(val1,val2,val3,'XYZ'));

   object.rotation.x = vec.x;
   object.rotation.y = vec.y;
   object.rotation.z = vec.z;
```

these?
Also any ideas why cant we do a YZY rotation in three.js?

Sorry if the question is not so clear, to be honest i feel unclear about all these :)

Comment: What do you expect, how it should behave, and how does it actually behave?

Comment: I edited the question. I expect that rotation.x or y or z after one another do the rotations in a sequence. So i can achieve a yzy rotation, then render the frame.